# Entering Germany with COVID-19 border regulations

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, covid-19, german-language, blue-card

Need some advice... I am currently home in NYC (american citizen), was supposed to return to Germany next week (April 5) but before I try to reschedule (which is a separate issue), I was wondering if I would even be allowed in. I currently have a Blue Card expiring 12/2023. I've emailed the consulate and their response is:

*The temporary travel restriction must exempt nationals of all EU Member States and Schengen Associated States, for the purposes of returning to their homes. This exemption must apply to:
- all EU citizens...
- third-country nationals who are long-term residents under the Long-term Residence Directive and persons deriving their right to reside from other EU Directives or national law or who hold national long-term visas.*

So my question is, is the Blue Card considered a "long-term resident"? I can't find a clear answer online. Any one else in a similar situation? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Thank you all! 
@Willeke you are correct, I am "home" in NYC on holiday to visit family but reside in Berlin. I also confirmed with the consulate again, and they explicitly told me that if I take a direct flight to Germany and have my address registration (Anmeldung), then legally I can enter, however it will be up to the discretion of the border agent. I leave this Saturday so fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a purely practical answer without digging too much into the academics.

Your first concern needs to be getting on the flight. For this, airport staff will use the TIMATIC database, which states:

> Passengers arriving from a non-Schengen Member State are not allowed to enter Germany.
>
> This does not apply to passengers with long-term
> right of residence (residence permit or longer-term visa) in an EEA
> Member States, Switzerland or the United Kingdom, returning home

A Blue card is a residence permit - Aufenthaltstitel - the word being printed on the card.

Now, the information in TIMATIC comes from section 22 of the *Bundespolizeipräsidium*, and as such is bound to be correct. Therefore, you can fly to and re-enter Germany.

Comment: This should be fine. The blue card is just an EU common format residence permit, and any airline staff who have been working for more than a week will recognize them instantly.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, is the Blue Card considered a "long-term resident"?

Someone with a blue card is not a "long-term resident[] under the Long-term Residence Directive."  However, such a person *is* a "person[] deriving [a] right to reside from...national law."  Therefore, the bearer of a valid German blue card should be permitted to return to a home in Germany.

The term "long-term resident" denotes a beneficiary of [Directive 2003/109/EC of 25 November 2003 concerning the status of third-country nationals who are long-term residents](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02003L0109-20110520), referred to in the quoted text as "the Long-term Residence Directive."  To be a beneficiary of this directive, you must have lived in Germany for at least five years.

However, the text that you have received from the consulate seems like a judicial or other decision that places limits on the "temporary travel restriction," not a description of the actual terms of the restriction itself.  Without more context from the message you received, it's impossible to say what the terms of the restriction actually are.

At [Coronavirus and entry restrictions: 4 things travelers to Germany need to know](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/coronavirus), which is five days old as of this writing, the German foreign ministry says that it will allow foreigners holding *any* residence permit for another EU country to transit through Germany in order to return to the country of residence, but they do not explicitly cover non-Germans who reside in Germany:

> EU-citzens and citizens of Great Britain, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway and Switzerland and their family members will be allowed to transit through Germany to reach their home countries. The same will apply for foreigners holding a residence permit in one of these countries.

However, any residence permit is probably included in "a national long-term visa," even though it is not strictly speaking a visa.  Your blue card is a residence permit, so you are probably fine to return home.

Comment: -1 You are making a simple matter complicated, mixing up terminology. Statement from the German Interior Ministry (now added to my answer): Persons who are not of German nationality may enter under the following conditions: To travel home to Germany to their usual place of residence or domicile.

Comment: The original statement also states: to third-country nationals with a longer-term right of residence (**residence title** or longer-term visa). A Blue Card is one form of a **residence title**.

Comment: @MarkJohnson no, the question mixes up the terminology.  I am sorting that out by explaining what "long-term residents under the Long-term Residence Directive" actually means.  Have you read that directive?  As to your second comment, that is precisely what the last paragraph of this answer suggests, though the "original statement" in the question does not use the term "residence title" at all.  If it did, there would be no need to speculate.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I've added a thesis statement to the beginning of this answer to make that clearer.

Comment: My answer, is however, the correct and direct answer to this question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson You have not removed or corrected the statement "long is anything that is at least 3 months," which, in the context of Directive 2003/109/EC, is clearly incorrect.  This can only increase the questioner's confusion about the phrase "long-term residents under the Long-term Residence Directive" in the response received from the consulate.  It is difficult to see how a claim that your answer is correct could prevail.

Comment: And I will not, because the OP question is about a German Blue Card (which doesn't exist in all EU Countries) is a **Aufenthaltstitel** (and thus allows **long term** stay= **längerfristigen Aufenthalts**) which is explicitly meantione in the original ban. Please learn how German is to be read and *unterstood* properly before downvoting other correct answers.

Comment: Please also remember *only* the text in the legal language (in this case German) is **legaly binding** - not any (possibly miscontructed) foreign language version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106047/discussion-between-phoog-and-mark-johnson).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the Blue Card is one form of a residence permit.

Long is anything that is at least 3 months.

Within Germany, returning to your place of residence is considered a valid travel reason.

Assuming you have your card with you, you should have no problems with either the Airline or Border guards.

> [Personen, die nicht die deutsche Staatsangehörigkeit haben, dürfen unter folgenden Bedingungen einreisen](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/kurzmeldungen/DE/2020/03/corona-ein-und-ausreise.html) :
>   ...
>   Zur Heimreise nach Deutschland zum **gewöhnlichen Aufenthaltsort bzw. Wohnsitz**.
>
> > Persons who are not of German nationality may enter under the following conditions:
> >     ...
> >     To travel home to Germany to their **usual place of residence or domicile**.

This should be clear enough for *everyone* to understand.

The German term **längerfristigen Aufenthalts** means, as it is used in the German law terminology, *long term presence* (can be longer than 90 days).

[Kurzfristiger Aufenthalt](https://germania.diplo.de/ru-de/service/05-VisaEinreise/kurzfristigeAufenthalt/-/1600140) is the opposite, *short term presence* (presence of maximum 90 days - C-Visa, Schengen Visa).

The meaning of these terms should not be confused with similar terminology used in **other** jurasdictions where the definition may be different. In translations 
*residence* is often used, but should not be confused with **residence permit** or a D-Visa (which allows a long term presence).

---

**Sources**:

- [BMI - Alle Meldungen - Wichtige Hinweise zu vorübergehenden Grenzkontrollen und Einreisebeschränkungen](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/kurzmeldungen/DE/2020/03/corona-ein-und-ausreise.html)

Comment: Under the "Long-term Residence Directive," the word "long" means five years, not three months.  A blue card holder is not necessarily a long-term resident.  Therefore, the answer to the explicit question 'is the Blue Card considered a "long-term resident"?' is *no.*  However, a blue card probably counts as a long-term visa even though, strictly speaking, it is not.  Therefore, the answer to the implicit question "Can I go home to Germany?" is probably *yes.*

Comment: @phoog No, what you mean is permanent. National visas are based on **National** laws. D-Visa werden auch in Fällen eines beabsichtigten **längerfristigen Aufenthalts** in der Regel für zunächst 90 Tage erteilt (vgl. aber Ziff. 6.4.2.1 der Verwaltungsvorschrift zum AufenthG)

Comment: @phoog Under German residence laws your have either **Aufenthaltserlaubnis** or **Niederlassungserlaubnis**. both are **längerfristigen Aufenthalts** (long term residence) to distinguish from **short term** which are restricted to a maximum of 90 days.

Comment: No, what I mean is *long-term.*  The phrase *permanent residence* is reserved for those who qualify under Directive 2004/38/EC.  The directive 2003/109/EC, *which is the specific, explicit subject of this question,* uses the term "long-term resident," as you can see if you follow the link in my answer.  The corresponding terms in the German-language directives are *Daueraufenthalt* and *langfristig Aufenthaltsberechtigter.*  A "long-term resident's EC residence permit’" as defined in 2003/109/EC is issued under national law *that must conform to the directive.*  That's what directives are.

Comment: You are confusing long-term visas as defined by the Schengen Visa Code with long-term residence as defined by 2003/109/EC.  The threshold in the second case is five years, and only a Niederlassungserlaubnis is a 'long-term resident's EC residence permit’ within the meaning of 2003/109/EC, which is the meaning explicitly sought in the question.

Comment: Having now looked at [AufenthG section 4(1)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__4.html) in connection with [our chat elsewhere](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105911/discussion-between-phoog-and-mark-johnson), I see that *Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt – EU (§ 9a)* is listed separately from *Niederlassungserlaubnis (§ 9),* so I now question whether even a Niederlassungserlaubnis counts as a 'long-term resident's EC residence permit’ within the meaning of 2003/109/EC.

Comment: No, I believe you don't understand the *shade* of meaning of the term **längerfristigen Aufenthalts**. It is used in the context of *long term presence in** and the nearest in English is  the word residencre. §9 is a pure National type, § 9a is an implemented EU law. § 9 can be granted after 3 years for a Blue Card holder under certain conditions, otherwise 5. § 9a can only be granted after 5 years.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106021/discussion-between-phoog-and-mark-johnson).

Comment: @Crazydre the chat is open for your participation.  The term "permanent residence" is reserved for beneficiaries of the free movement directive.  "Long-term resident" is defined in directive 2003/109/EC, and it is that definition that is explicitly at issue here, and the threshold for that status is five years.  You can't wave away a discussion about legal definitions when the term being asked about is "long-term residents under the Long-term Residence Directive."

Comment: @phoog This question is **only** about if a holder of a Blue Card may return to Germany. Nothing more.

Comment: @MarkJohnson why aren't you using the chat?  The question is, in fact, explicitly: 'is the Blue Card considered a "long-term resident"?'  That question is asked in the context of a statement about "long-term residents under the Long-term Residence Directive."  The question is therefore about the definition of "long-term resident."  Article 4(1) of the directive states "Member States shall grant long-term resident status to third-country nationals who have resided legally and continuously within its territory for five years immediately prior to the submission of the relevant application."

Comment: @phoog The actual question was whether OP can re-enter Germany

Comment: @Crazydre why are you still not using the chat?  If you were, you would see my mention there of the X-Y problem.  It may be that OP wants to know whether he can get in to Germany, but what he actually explicitly asked was 'So my question is, is the Blue Card considered a "long-term resident"?'  The question is asked in response to the phrase "long-term residents under the Long-term Residence Directive."  Since a long-term resident under the long-term residence directive has rights that blue card holders do not have, it's important to be precise.

Comment: @phoog Sent a chat message